# Migration Wizard Offline SQL Server to Oracle, before Move Data, directory Data is empty

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, migration

I'm migrating data that be in SQL Server to Oracle

I'm doing it Offline, I generated .ocp, I ran the OMWB_OFFLINE_CAPTURE.bat, I passed the parameters and generated two directories, one called Master and other with name of my Database in SQL Server, in that case called db_GFA and I granted privileges to user

After I executed the Migration Wizard Offline, I catched the sqlserver2008.ocp file, I Converted types data and didn't traslate the Objects, because I want just the data, and I executed the Move Data e generated the directory called DATAMOVE, **but the directory "Data", in DATAMOVE, is empty, didn't brought the data**

Someone can help me? I need that data

Comment: I can't find anything relevant (ie: recent and not yours) for `OMWB_OFFLINE_CAPTURE.bat` through google.  My skills may be lacking.  Since you are having so many problems with this tool, I recommend you use SQL*Developer and its Migration Workbench feature.

Comment: I was using the SQL Developer and your Migration Workbench, but I already resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a thing

After you executed **Move Data**, remember that Migration is between SQL Server to Oracle, the SQL Developer generate some scripts and one of that scripts generated, call **MicrosoftSQLServer_data.bat**, you must run that script and it'll bring the data to you complete the Migration